# call logs on iOS devices

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am wondering is there any way to show on my own app call list like recent calls, missing calls etc. I need to get to this data and show it to user in my app. I need to know is there any access to this data on iOS using swift? I know that there are some questions on StackOverflow about this but maybe something changes from that time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to access this data on non-jailbroken device.

Comment: I won't downvote this, but being just a single line, should be added as a comment. There are couple of existing answers for this with good explanation. Perhaps you might want to point out to those **in question comments**